# Trying to understand functions of operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

**Notation**: Let $a,b,m,M\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $a<m\leq M<b$, and let $A$ be a self-adjoint bounded operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ satisfying $mI\leq A\leq MI$. Let $K[a,b]$ denote the set of all piecewise continuous bounded functions which are monotone decreasing limits of continuous functions. Consider the function
$$
e_\lambda(t):= \begin{cases}
                 1, & t\leq\lambda \\
                 0, & t>\lambda.    \tag{1}
               \end{cases}
$$
Obviously $e_\lambda(t)\in K[a,b]$ and so we can define $e_\lambda(A)$. Let $E_\lambda:=e_\lambda(A)$.

My first question is the following: The way that $e_\lambda(A)$ is defined is to be the limit of polynomials $P_n(A)$, where $P_n(t)$ are polynomials that approximate (via Weierstrass approximation theorem) the sequence of functions $\varphi_n(t)\in C[a,b]$, which they themselves approximate the function $e_\lambda(t)$. That is, $\lim P_n(A):=e_\lambda(A):=E_\lambda$. But is it true that one can write
$$
E_\lambda:=e_\lambda(A) = \begin{cases}
                            I, & A\leq\lambda I \\
                            0, & A>\lambda I,    \tag{2}
                          \end{cases}
$$
where $I$ and $0$ are the identity and zero operators, respectively?

Next the author$^{[1]}$ gives the following example:

> **Example**: Let $A$ be a compact self-adjoint operator: $Ax=\sum\lambda_k\langle x,e_k \rangle e_k$. Then $E_\lambda x=\sum_{\lambda_k\leq\lambda}\langle x,e_k \rangle e_k$ for $\lambda<0$ and
> $$
> E_\lambda x= x-\sum_{\lambda_k>\lambda}\langle x,e_k \rangle e_k\tag{3}
> $$
> for $\lambda>0$.

And to be straightforward: I don't understand this at all. It'd be helpful if someone could really break down what is going on here. For instance, it seems that $(2)$ can't be true, since then in the example above $E_\lambda x$ would only ever equal $I x$ or $0 x$, correct?

---

$^{[1]}$ The text is Functional Analysis: An Introduction by Eidelman-milman-tsolomitis; more specifically, chapter 7 of the text.